# How to write an abstract main class

Tags: java, program-entry-point, abstract

I need to write some importers. They need all the same initialization. So I try to write an abstract class, which does all the initialization and also has the main method, so that all sub-classes just need to implement `run()` to do their specific import work:

```
public abstract class AbstractImporter {

    public AbstractImporter() {
        // Initialization
    }

    public abstract void run();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        AbstractImporter importer = new AbstractImporter();
        importer.run();
    }

}

public class ConcreteClass() {

  public void run() {
    // Do some importing  
  } 

}
```

Of course it fails to create an instance of this abstract class (`new AbstractImporter()`).

Does anybody has any idea how to solve that? TIA!

Comment: What do you want the main method to do?

Comment: @JBNizet I like to avoid the main method in concrete sub clases, so the main method of this abstract super class should instantiate the sub class and call the run method.

Comment: how u will instantiate the child class in the parent class main method ?? Are you sure what you want to do ??

Comment: @tech-idiot No. You are right. It may be too late ... ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Obviously you need a concrete class - anonymous or otherwise.

Better to move the main method to another class and instantiate the appropriate concrete class based on data (either your domain specific or a constant) and then run it. This way each implementation can be independent of other implementations.

```
public abstract class AbstractImporter {

    public AbstractImporter() {
        // Initialization
    }

    public abstract void run();
}

public class ConcreteImporter1 extends AbstractImporter {
    public void run() {
        //do something
    }
}


public class ImporterMain() {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        AbstractImporter importer = createImporter(args[1]);
        importer.run();
    }

    private static AbstractImporter createImporter(String type) {
        if (type.equals("1")) {
            return new ConcreteImporter1();
        }
        ....
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
new AbstracterImporter() { 
  public void run() { 
    // ... 
  } 
};
```

I apologize for current lack of formatting, currently on a mobile device.

Comment: Sorry I never noticed, didn't mean to edit it after but I typo'd, meant to add in a `void` before `run`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. When I create a sub-class of this with a valid `run()` method, and I call the main-method of its super-class, than the `run()` method of the anonymous class is called and not the one of my sub-class

Comment: @t777: of course your subclasses aren't running! You have to create an object of the subclass, not of the anonymous class.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels So the subclass needs its own run method. But I like to avoid that (if possible).

Comment: @t777: re `"So the subclass needs its own run method."` -- that makes no sense. If you want your instance to be an instance of a subclass, you must *make it an instance of that subclass*, either by calling new on that subclass, or with some factory method.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels You are right. This makes no sense at all. Sorry for my confustion.

Answer (score 0):

```
public abstract class AbstractImporter {

    public AbstractImporter() {
        // Initialization
    }

    public abstract void run();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        AbstractImporter importer = new AbstractImporter(){
            public void run() {
                System.out.println("Anonymous implementation");
            }
        };
        importer.run();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot create an instance of an abstract class.

```
public abstract class AbstractImporter {

public AbstractImporter() {
    // Initialization
}

public abstract void run();

}

public class ConcreteClass extends AbstractImporter{

    public void run(){
            //Implementation

    }         

    public static void main(String args[]){

            AbstractImporter ai = new ConcreteClass();
            ai.run();

     }

}
```